# MYSQL count first table ids where value is found in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables,

**table1** and **table2** both tables has these columns

```
id, name, rel_id
```

now i would like to have a query to count ids of the **table1** where name from **table2** is equals to john and **table1** rel_id equals to **table2** rel_id. 
so something like this (this is not correct that's why i need help to make it work).

```
Select count(ids) from table1
where table2.name="john" 
and table1.rel_id=table2.rel_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, one way is to use a join:

```
Select count(t1.id)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.rel_id = t2.rel_id
where t2.name = 'john';
```

Note that this uses table aliases to distinguish all the columns in each table.  Because the tables have the same columns, you need to identify the table for each column.  Also, the I changed the string constant to use single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: +1 : potentially this may require a distinct count, depending on the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into joins so :

`select count(ids) 
from table1 join table2 on table1.rel_id=table2.rel_i
where table2.name="john"`

A short intro from W3C schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

The full MySQL URL for more reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html